# Parse.com saving non logged in users

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform

I am building an iOS app with a following/follower relation using Parse.com. I am trying to do something where every time a user follows another user it puts the follower into to an array of Followers in Parse.com but i can not save a user who is not logged in. Is there anyway to get around this using the iOS SDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to save a user that is not the current user, you will have to use cloud code and the master key. You can send up the id of the user you want to change, query for that user, and change any fields you want. Here is my cloud code function for editing users, where "myUser" is the id I sent up:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("editUser", function(request, response) {
  //var GameScore = Parse.Object.extend("SchoolHappening");
  // Create a new instance of that class.
  //var gameScore = new GameScore();
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

  var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
query.get(request.params.myUser, {
  success: function(myUser) {
    // The object was retrieved successfully.
    myUser.set("cabinetPosition", request.params.myPosition);
    // Save the user.
      myUser.save(null, {
        success: function(myUser) {
          // The user was saved successfully.
          response.success("Successfully updated user.");
        },
        error: function(gameScore, error) {
          // The save failed.
          // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and description.
          response.error("Could not save changes to user.");
        }
      });

  },
  error: function(object, error) {
    // The object was not retrieved successfully.
    // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and description.
  }
});

});
```

You can learn more about cloud code in the parse docs.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set an array property in your follower user (logged in) which represents the id of users he actually follows. Each time you follows another user, add his objectId in the array.

To get all your followers, use `whereKey:containsAllObjectsInArray:` method of `PFQuery`

```
PFQuery *followersQuery = [PFUser query];
[followersQuery whereKey:@"followsId" containsAllObjectsInArray:@[[PFUser currentUser].objectId]];
[followersQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *followersArray, NSError *error){
    // Do stg
}];
```

Comment: I have a following relation which is an array of the users someone is following. I am trying to get the count of followers for each user and i don't think i can accomplish that with that relation.

Comment: and be sure to call [PFUser enableAutomaticUser] within - application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:  to be able to save even users who did not logged in

Comment: If you want to know the count of followers for each user then this method isn't efficient, that's true. Have you tried using an intermediate PFObject subclass which represents the follower-following relations ? Without ACL, a follower can edit the followed table.